# Non-complete bipartite graph notation

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

How to denote a non-complete bipartite graphs? Because as far as I know, $K_{m, n}$ notation is only for complete bipartite graphs.

Comment: I've only heard of $((A,B), E)$ or some very similar things.

Comment: One would denote a bipartite graph as $G = (U, V, E)$, where $U$ and $V$ are parts of the partition of the graph and $E$ denotes the edges of the graph. As per: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)

Comment: Most graphs don't have individual names.